# Работа со звуком в python3

Tags: python-3.x

Подскажите библиотеки для работы со звуком, pyaudio не могу установить, тк нужен python2.7, по крайней мере как я прочитал. От библиотеки нужна возможность записи звука с микрофона и воспроизведение, также дальнейшая возможность сжатия в форматы speak и opus.

Comment: Я с таким тоже очень давно столкнулся... Сколько смотрел, читал, ничего не нашел, ответят скажи

Comment: проблему с записью вроде как решил `import sounddevice as sd
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
from opus.api import encoder

fs = 44100  # Частота дискретизации
seconds = 3  # Продолжительность записи

myrecording = sd.rec( int( seconds * fs ), samplerate = fs, channels = 2 )
sd.wait()  # Дождитесь окончания записи

write('output.raw', fs, myrecording)  # Сохранить как RAW файл`

Comment: Ну [тут](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) есть и для 3.x. Значит возможно.